# What's the meaning of this sentence? "You must have quite a travel agent."

Tags: spoken-english, intensifiers

Two questions here:

First question,someone said "first I went to Europe, then I went to France."(we know there's something wrong with the logic of it.)

and then someone replied "good, you must have a quite travel agent"

Can anyone tell me what's the meaning of "have a quite travel agent" I don't get that.

Second question: Dad asks Mom to join in playing skating with him and their daughter. Mom replied: I'd just be in the way. (since their daughter didn't know Mom would play also). My question is that "I'd just be in the way" is the meaning of "NO" or "I don't want to change your original plan"?

Comment: "you must have **quite** a travel agent!" = "your travel agent is not very good".

Comment: usually an adjective following the word "quite". Here has no adjective following quite. So it always means bad when there's no adjective? Like quite dog, quite man, quite boss=bad dog, bad man, bad boss??

Comment: @CowperKettle is either incorrect, or is assuming that the sentence was said sarcastically.

Comment: @Qing -- Both of your questions are worth answering -- but their answers do not share a common theme.  Please ask the second question as a separate question.  That will allow both questions to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. > 4. [quite a](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quite) (not used with a negative) of an exceptional, considerable, or noticeable kind: *quite a girl; quite a long walk*
   >   (Dictionary.com)

   I assume the speaker said "good, you must have ***quite* a** travel agent". This means the travel agent must have been good, or remarkable. Note that the speaker might have been speaking sarcastically.
2. > [in the way](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+way)
   >   Obstructing someone or interfering in something. *You can come into the kitchen to observe, but please try not to get in the way. Ugh, the neighbor always puts his trash cans in the way of my car. She's so determined that I just know nothing will get in the way of her plans to finish her thesis.*
   >   (TFD)

   The mom is indirectly indicating "no" by saying that she would be a hindrance (I'd just be *in the way* = *a hindrance*.)

Comment: Sure. Please try to ask one question per post and provide the research you have done to answer your question when possible. That's our usual guideline for asking questions.